# Avalonia Ui putting a UserControl inside another

Tags: c#, wpf, avaloniaui, avalonia

I need to do something like this code below:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.Views.UserControls.UCMainControl" 
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:dxb="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/bars"
             xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"
             xmlns:dxc="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"
             xmlns:dxnav="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/navigation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views.UserControls">

  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="220"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Controls:UCMenuPrincipal x:Name="MenuPrincipalcontrol" Grid.Row="0"/>

  </Grid>
```

In this code, I need to put a menu on another UserControl, but the Menu is in a different UserControl (however, it could be anything).

When the code is in normal WPF I can do it. Is it possible to do this with Avalonia?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure, what you are asking for, but I think you are trying to have a user control with a menu inside and then window hosting this user control with a menu.

Something like this should work:

```
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels;assembly=MyApp"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views.UserControls;assembly=MyApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
        x:Class="MyApp.Views.MainWindow"
        Icon="/Assets/avalonia-logo.ico"
        Title="MyApp">

    <uc:UCMainControl/>

</Window>
```

```
<UserControl xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views.UserControls;assembly=MyApp"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.UserControls.UCMainControl">

  <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,*,140" ColumnDefinitions="Auto,*,220">
    <uc:UCMenuPrincipal x:Name="MenuPrincipalcontrol" Grid.Row="0"/>
  </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

```
<UserControl xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.UserControls.UCMenuPrincipal">

  <Menu Background="AliceBlue">
    <MenuItem Header="File"/>
    <MenuItem Header="Edit"/>
    <MenuItem Header="Help"/>
  </Menu>

</UserControl>
```

[result window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/angsd.png)